# Coldfusion: Multiple Form Fields, One Submit

Tags: coldfusion, insert

**Summary:**

- the insert works.
- the cfc works

the problem is when i add the "**_#i#**" to the end of the field names!

**Detail:**

I have a variable amount of form fields that need to be inserted in to the db at the same time, different rows.

so I looped the form and incremented the name of the fields.

so I have title_1, title_2, title_3 etc...

next I wanted to insert them in the database (one submit button) by looping the insert by the amount of form fields.

I'm using **ColdFusion Server Standard 8,0,1,195765**

The Error:
**Invalid CFML construct**

I've tried all sorts - any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
     <cfoutput>
        <cfloop from="1" to ="#VARIABLES.fieldTotal#" index="i">
        <cfset VARIABLES.insert = theObj.the_insert(
                the_id  = FORM.the_id_#i#
            ,   title   = FORM.title_#i#
            ,   author  = FORM.author_#i#
            ,   caption = FORM.caption_#i#
        )>
        </cfloop>
    </cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
form[ "the_id_#i#" ]
```

All ColdFusion scopes are structures and can be accessed this way.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know I could do this. Much appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer is already given by Sam Farmer, but just to clarify how accessing struct members works:

`FORM.var` is equal to `FORM["var"]`

Access **using a dot will not get evaluated** though. Whenever you want to dynamically access members in structs, you need to use square brackets.

`FORM["the_id_#i#"]` is equal to `FORM["the_id_" & i]`.

And remember to sanitize user inputs (especially GET/URL and POST/FORM data):

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#VARIABLES.fieldTotal#" index="i">
    <cfif structKeyExists(FORM, "the_id_" & i) and reFind("^[0-9]+$", FORM["the_id_" & i])
        and structKeyExists(FORM, "title_" & i)
        and structKeyExists(FORM, "author_" & i)
        and structKeyExists(FORM, "caption_" & i)>

        <cfset VARIABLES.insert = theObj.the_insert(
            the_id  = FORM["the_id_" & i],
            title   = FORM["title_" & i],
            author  = FORM["author_" & i],
            caption = FORM["caption_" & i]
        )>

    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

`structKeyExists(FORM, "the_id_" & i)` is equal to `isDefined("FORM.the_id_#i#")`.